# Creating meta-data for binary chunks for sending via WebRTC datachannel

Tags: javascript, browser, blob, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I have a datachannel connection between two browsers, and would like to break a file into chunks and send them to/from the clients.

I can read the file and break it up into chunks just fine. However I need a way for the receiving client to know

1. which file the chunk of data relates to (unique identifier).
2. which place the chunk applies to in reconstruction (index number).

When transferring binary data in the browser, it seems the entire payload must be binary. So I can't, for example, create a JSON object with the above properties, and have a `data` property with the actual binary chunk.

I guess I need to wrap the file chunk into a secondary binary blob which contains the identifier and index. The receiving client would then decode the first, wrapper, chunk to check the meta-data, then handle the actual file chunk based on that information.

How can I do this in the browser? I have done a lot of google searching but can't seem to find any information on this, so wonder if I'm perhaps overlooking something which can help ease this process?

Comment: Just build your own protocol using the typed arrays like [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? I have been reading about the various javascript APIs for dealing with Binary data but I'm still pretty confused by it and have yet to find solid examples of how I could achieve something like I described above.

Comment: See my answer below. I am working with `Dart` rather than `JavaScript`, so I can't really provide an example for you.

Comment: @NickJennings not to be mean-spirited, but his answer completely covers all bases of your question, and I think a good rule of thumb is questions without code will generally receive answers without code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create your own protocol for transfering files.

1. I assume you have a `File`/`Blob` object. You probably also use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice) method to get chunks.
2. You can simply use a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) to transfer data.

   1. Create a protocol that satisfies your needs, for example:

      - 1 byte: Package type (255 possible package types)
      - 2 bytes: Length of data (2^16 bytes ~ 64KB of data per chunk)
      - n bytes: <Data>
   2. Send an initial package (e.g. type 0x01)

      - Data contains some information (all or some):

        - Total length of blob/file
        - file type
        - chunk size
        - number of chunks
        - filename
        - ...
   3. Send Chunks of data (e.g. type 0x02)

      - You should use at least two bytes for a sequence number
      - Data follows afterwards (no length needed because you know the total length)

*Note*: If transfering multiple files, you should add a id or something else.

On the receiver side you can wait for the initial package and and create a new `Uint8Array` with length of the total file. Afterwards you can use [`set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) to add received data at the chunk position (offset = `0-based-chunk-number`*`chunk-size`). When all chunks are received, you can create the `Blob`.

Comment: Thanks for the overview, this is what I was thinking, but seeing it explained in a more pragmatic sense helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Robert's very good answer, you can use channel.send(blob) (at least in Firefox<->Firefox).  Eventually  this should work in Chrome as well.

Comment: thus 'Eventually' :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a simple matter of multiple files, you could just create a new data channel for each new file.

Each channel will take care of it's own buffering, sequence etc.

Something like:

```
chan = peerCon.createDataChannel("/somedir/somefile", props);
```

then break your file into <64k chunks and `chan.send()` them in sequence.

The receiving side can get the label and use it to save the file appropriately

```
peerCon.ondatachannel = function(channel) {
     console.log("New file " + channel.label);
     channel.onmessage = function(
```

etc.

P.S.
If you really must use a file system protocol over a single channel (say because you want random access behaviour) don't invent a new one, use one that already exists and is tested - I'm fond of 9p from inferno/plan9